# PCB Fabrication and Circuit Designing

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

What are the best resources and options available to initiate learning and practicing circuit designing and PCB fabrication?

Any particular website, books or other such recommendable resources?

Comment: This is off topic and too broad.  It'll probably be closed.  That said:  Find something simple you'd like to make, learn about it, see how others solve similar problems.  Build and modify circuits the others have designed.  Find a schematic design program and use it to redraw the circuits and layout PCBs.  Have fun.

Comment: [Kicad is free](https://kicad.org/). There also free versions of commercial programs like Eagle, but those usually have restrictions on size or number of layers or number parts that can make it difficult to get into more advanced things.  Once you start with one, you are unlikely to want to learn a new just to make a PCB that exceeds the limits - you end up purchasing the full version.  Kicad is not artificially limited.  It is free as in freedom, no just free as in "free beer." [Edited by a moderator.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm also interested in this topic. My plan when I get time is to download Autodesk Eagle for free [AutoDesk Eagle](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/free-download) and go to youtube on how to use it. The free version advertises "PCB design software intended for hobbyists and makers." so I'm assuming there should no problem with posting it on this website.

Comment: So your answer is "Use youtube"?

Comment: Youtube is not a good way to learn technical material.

Comment: Bort and JRE - referencing his above question "initiate learning and practicing circuit designing and PCB fabrication" I see nothing wrong with using youtube as a first step for learning. I'll agree it is far from the best in terms of providing material that has been checked, but you cannot deny that with careful selection, one could learn enough to get started into pcb design and fabrication, which would appear to satisfy what Jay is looking for.

Comment: Yep, YouTube is a truly good source for initial phase. Although, won't depend on videos all the way.  AutoDesk Eagle sounds pretty awesome. Also Kicad.

Comment: @xctom5593 Thank You for the suggestion.

Comment: @xctom5593 - I wasn't implying that youtube isn't helpful. I was however implying that your answer was a bit lackluster for stackexchange. I would be shocked if someone wasn't aware of youtube. That being said, there wasn't much you could do with such a lackluster and off-topic question to begin with.